# How to add lwc quick action to the profile tab in field service mobile app

Tags: lightning-web-components, field-service-lightning

I created a quick action button of lwc type.
I'm trying to add it to the profile tab actions. I thought it was the service Resource layout, so I added the button there, but it's not showing.
When I added the button to the ServiceAppointment layout, the button showed up.
How do I add the button to the profile tab?

[image: profile tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I need to create global action with my LWC, add that global action to the global publisher layout. To be able to do that, it's necessary to  add targets to the LWC meta.xml :

```
<targets>
        <target>lightning__GlobalAction</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
```